# Parse JSON dynamically in c# (.NET) show on ASP.NET MVC PAGE

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I have a project where a user can enter a REST url - any url onto a field on a web page - which returns a JSON response. I want to be to be able to read the response, and extract the data keys in the response. I have seen several examples for dynamically reading JSON, but they all depend on knowing what the response structure would look like. There's no concept of WSDL in json, so how I can parse the response and show the user the data structure on the page.

An example after user enters the url and my web appl reads the json response. I need to show the keys to the user. How do I get that information out? and eventually use it to read the json itself in c#?

```
Personal Information
         Name
         Age
         Sex
Finance
        Withdrawals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, on your page, javascript knows all about json, and it's very easy to navigate, so once on your client, you can easily display it how you like.

If you want .NET to understand it, then you can use newtonsoft Json.NET and it will parse Json and let you programmatically navigate the structure.

If you are allowing any json, then you need to work out what you want to display given any json document, It's not very complex in that jsons structure is relatively straightforward and you just need to iterate keys and follow the nesting / arrays

Comment: Thanks for the response. You have given ma a great direction to go since I can make an ajax call with the entered url and then iterate the keys. The major problem I still have is how to show only one unique object properties. For example, if the response is an array, I want to show the keys for only one item, but the disadvantage is that the particular object might not have all the keys. What do you suggest to do here? Alternatively, is there any way for my users to define the structure of a JSON object without my app trying to figure it out?

Comment: Hard for me to say, I'm not quite what your goal is.  If the response is an array, you could have many different kinds of json objects within that array, or all the same kind.